# Extract Timestamps of an audio file when loud noises occur, python

Tags: python

I have an audio file in wav format, I would like extract particular timestamps from duration of audio where the loudness is significantly high.

For examples, Consider speech commentaries of sports game , my goal is to identify a timestamp in audio where the commentator shouts for a specific highlight in on-going game.
Python is the priority

Expected output:
start(seconds)  end(seconds)
[0.81, 2.429] etc

```
def target_amplitude(sound, target_dBFS): 
  diff_in_dBFS = target_dBFS - sound.dBFS 
  return sound.apply_gain(diff_in_dBFS) 
verified_sound = target_amplitude(vid_aud, -20.0) 
nonsilent_data = detect_nonsilent(verified_sound, min_silence_len=500, silence_thresh=-20, seek_step=1) 
for chunks in nonsilent_data:
chunk=[chunk/1000 for chunk in chunks] 
time_list.append(chunk)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share the code you've written to attempt to solve this issue, and point out the part that isn't working?

Comment: Welcome! Sorry, but what you ask isn't our thing around here. Please review [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a specific question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Comment: def target_amplitude(sound, target_dBFS):
    diff_in_dBFS = target_dBFS - sound.dBFS
    return sound.apply_gain(diff_in_dBFS)
normalized_sound = target_amplitude(vid_aud, -20.0)
nonsilent_data = detect_nonsilent(normalized_sound, min_silence_len=500, silence_thresh=-20, seek_step=1)
for chunks in nonsilent_data:
    chunk=[chunk/1000 for chunk in chunks]
    time_list.append(chunk)

Comment: this code helps me to extract time stamps which are not silent or where there is at least noise , Sorry if I'm doing anything wrong in stack overflow. Today is my first day.

Comment: Include your code with your question and not as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

This is not actually very hard.  The `wave` module can read a wave file.  `numpy can tell you which array elements are outside of a range.

```
import wave
import numpy as np

w = wave.open('sound.wav')
sam = w.readframes(w.getnframes())
sam = np.frombuffer(sam, dtype=np.int16)

bigpos = np.where( sam > 20000 )
bigneg = np.where( sam < -20000 )
```

This assumes you have a wave file.  If you have an MP3, you'll have to deccode it.